# how to properly show an image with a transperent layer with html css

Tags: html, css, image, transparency

despite the simplicity of the issue, I could not find a solution, I have an image with a transparent layer that should be render like this :

[image]

it is rendered like this :

[image]

and I have tried many things like making the background of the image and its container div transparent

```
   .thearticle {
     background-color: transparent;
     /*background-color: white;*/
   }
   .thearticle img {
     background-color: transparent;
   }
```

what am I missing ?

Comment: PLease include all relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: .thearticle  - remove background transparent from the div, that's one of the reason its all black

Comment: with and without the background transparent it is all black, there is nothing special about the relevant html and css; there is  bootstrap stuff  and I could include all the css styles but they all concern padding and other irrelevant styles